# unable to add PWA app to home screen, error Home Screen Layout Locked

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I have a PWA app which works fine on all phones including my phone which is a MI phone. I have a download app button which fires the installation banner.

But on one of other Samsung phone, install button doesn't work. It doesn't fire banner at all. And if I try to go manually by selecting "Add To Home Screen" from Menu, it shows instalation pop up but after clicking add displays error.

> Can't Add "App Name" To Home Screen. Home screen layout locked.

Please help.

Comment: That seems like it may be a setting on THAT Samsung device? Probably nothing to do with your PWA.

Comment: Thanks @Mathias, yes I just checked that Samsung J6 setting. Found the culprit. Thanks.

Comment: Interesting. I have not heard of that before. What was the name of the setting? I'd like to research more to see if there is a way to detect it.

Comment: Hi @Mathias, it was a Samsung J6 and option was under Settings >> Display >> Cant remember exactly but something related to "Screen Lock". According to them this setting is used to avoid accidental uninstall of apps from the screen.